# How to resize NestedScroll view to height of childlayout

Tags: android, xml

i have a nested scrollview which contains some textview and a Map.
Unfortunately is the height of my Nestedscrollview not the same as my Childlayout. There is always a White space at the end of my Layout. Here is my XML Code from my activity_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tata"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/collaas"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="@color/schwarz"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagel"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logoooo"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarl"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/trasparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<include layout="@layout/content_detail" />
```

and here is the XML Code of nestedscrollview layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView                                    mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detailevents">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fsk"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@color/trasparent"></RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/infor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="Information:"
            android:textColor="@color/detailtxt"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:src="@drawable/info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/information"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/infor"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="test teest"
            android:textColor="@color/schwarz"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/info"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/info"
        android:layout_below="@+id/info">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="Entrance Fee:"
            android:textColor="@color/detailtxt"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/moni" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="25 €"
            android:textColor="@color/schwarz"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/clock" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="Oppening Times:"
            android:textColor="@color/detailtxt"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/opening"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"


            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"></Spinner>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/age" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"

            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="Agegroup:"
            android:textColor="@color/detailtxt"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="23 - 99 Years"
            android:textColor="@color/schwarz"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout


        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/address" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/postalcode"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="Address:"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:text="Testweg 6"
            android:textColor="@color/schwarz"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postalcode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/address"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/address"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:text="85653 Aying"
            android:textColor="@color/schwarz"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After this Map Fragment i always get this white space except i increase the height of my map fragment but this should be 250dp.